# Webcam on MSI GS70 stealth not working

Tags: windows-8.1, drivers, webcam

I have a MSI GS70 stealth with a built in webcam. I have many troubles trying to get it working.

In Device Manager, the webcam is register under imaging devices, USB boot. I cannot use the webcam on Skype or the Windows 8.1 camera app even though the laptop detected the webcam and device manager shows that the device is working properly. Normally when you turn the webcam on, there will be a LED beside the webcam that will turn on but in this case, the LED does not turn on(meaning webcam is not operating).

I had tried to find a driver for it on the MSI website but there was none available. I had tried the Fn+F6 functions on the keyboard to turn the webcam on and off multiple times but the webcam is still not working.

Right now I do not know if this is a hardware or a software issue and MSI is not very helpful in giving troubleshooting tips for this matter.

Is there any MSI GS70 users out there that can shed some light on this matter. It has been bugging me for 2 months with no webcam to Skype.

Comment: Did it ever work? Is it still under warranty?

Comment: It worked fine few days ago. I can turn it on and off and Device Manager can detect it. It just doesnt have the LED lit up as it should when the webcam is turn.

Comment: Do you have any steps to follow which could help me get it working? Mine is having the same issues ;(

Comment: after some checks, it appear to be a hardware problem. so the best way is             to send it back to the official dealer. Build quality is not the best for the GS70. Any slight bumps could disconnect cable in the laptop and access is hard.